# Update listivew entries

Tags: android, android-listview

I have a problem with *updating* entries of my custom `ListView`. I have implemented custom `ArrayAdapter` that populates my `ListView` as follows:

```
public class MealPartCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<MealPart> {
    private final Context context;
    private final ArrayList<MealPart> mealParts;

    public MealPartCustomAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MealPart> mealParts) {
        super(context, R.layout.add_meal_list_view_row, mealParts);
        this.context = context;
        this.mealParts = mealParts;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.add_meal_list_view_row, parent, false);

        AutoCompleteTextView mealPartProductNameTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mealPartAutoCompleteTextView);
        mealPartProductNameTextView.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, values));
        EditText quantityEditText = (EditText) rowView.findViewById(R.id.mealQuantityEditText);
        mealPartProductNameTextView.setText(mealParts.get(position).productName);
        quantityEditText.setText(Float.toString(mealParts.get(position).foodQuantity));

        return rowView;
    }
}
```

MealPart consists of two fields - foodName and foodQuantity in float. How can I implement updating rows of such data and see changes in `ArrayList<MealPart>` that I pass to custom `ArrayAdapter` ?

**UPDATE** Ok after looking at few answers I would like to exaplin a little bit. I know that this data will show up and I can edit it. I can also add new rows by this code:

```
public void onAddMealPartButtonClick(View view) {
        mealPartsAdapter.add(new MealPart());
    }
```

but I can't get to the point where to **hook up to event handler for text changed** inside one of edittext in one of rows as well as how to **reflect this change in underlying ArrayList** and where to fire `notifyDatasetChanged`.

This is onCreate method. I guess nothing new here.

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);    
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_meal);
        mealNameTextView =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.mealNameTextView);
        mealPartsListView = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.mealPartsListView);
        meal = new Meal();
        mealPartsAdapter = new MealPartCustomAdapter(this, meal.mealParts);
        mealPartsListView.setAdapter(mealPartsAdapter);
    }
```

Comment: Initially bound data appears but your custom adapter does not get effected by updates right? Can you add the code that you instantiate the adapter and bind it. And also the block you update and try to refresh would help alot

Comment: Please see my revised question.

Comment: We did, but no idea if you've had the solution yet

Answer (score 1):

```
YOUR_ADAPTER.notifyDatasetChanged();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding / removing / manipulation items in existing collection of your custom adapter `mealPartCustomAdapterInstance.notifyDataSetChanged()` would do the trick. But make sure you are calling it in `UI Thread` (call it inside `runOnUiThread()` if your trying to refresh it in a seperate thread)

Answer (score 0):

You just have to call the `notifyDatasetChanged()` method and it will update itself, simple as that.